# AngularJS using push() issue when I want to override the previous push() entry

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<p class="{{ UserMessageStyle }}" > Some Message </p>
```

And then in Angular Controller When I want to pass a specific class name to the 
variable `UserMessageStyle`, I do the following:

```
 $scope.UserMessageStyle = [];
if(condition_is_met)
{
 $scope.UserMessageStyle.push("alert-danger");
}
```

But my problem is that, when once the above statement is run, then I cannot change it. It has a reason because I have declared `UserMessageStyle` as `[]` which mean on each instance of `push()` a new key&value pair will be added.

My Question is that, how should I use `push()` where I don't want my `UserMessageStyle` to be an object or an array. I want it to be a simple variable which is overriden on each instance call of `push()`. Something like this:

```
// the declaration of the variable as an object is removed.
if(condition_is_met)
{
 $scope.UserMessageStyle.push("alert-danger");
}
```

But the above statement causes this error:

```
cannot read the property `push()` of undefined.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me that you are looking for a normal variable instead of an array.
why dont you do something like this:

```
if(condition_is_met)
{
     $scope.UserMessageStyle = "alert-danger";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do not need array here, class attribute understand space separated list

```
$scope.mystyles = "alert-danger alert-danger-bright"
```

and layout

```
<p class="{{ UserMessageStyle }}" > Some Message </p>
```

Also consider using `ng-class` directive for that

```
<p ng-class="UserMessageStyle" > Some Message </p>
```